# Sorting LinkedList with specific variable of object?

Tags: java, sorting, object

I have a bubble sort function that orders LinkedList of SomeObj by "a" variable. What if i want to order the list by "b" variable at the same time? What can i do instead of writing another function with b?

```
public static void BubbleSort(LinkedList<SomeObj> objs) {
    int len = objs.size();

    for(int pass = 1; pass < len; pass++) {
        for (int i=0; i < len - pass; i++) {
            if(objs.get(i).a > objs.get(i + 1).a) {
                SomeObj p = objs.get(i);
                objs.set(i,objs.get(i+1));
                objs.set(i + 1, p);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont use Comparable interface , use Comparator instead.
Comparable is suitable when you dont change the comparison criteria often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Implement Comparator interface** in a class with its compare method.
that accepts two objects and compares them which returns -ve,0,+ve values to tell less than , equal or greater than.

create an object of this Comparator and pass it to bubble sort method and let it use its compare method to compare the two object.

Your object should have getters for all such fields.

Also whenever you wanna change the object's criteria for comparison , use a different Comparator.

Check this  [example](http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/java-example/java-comparator-example.html).

Comment: To be exact the interface may not return -1 or 1. Just <0, respectively >0.

Comment: You should probably make the signatures generic for the sake of re-use.  For an example of the signatures, see the Collections.sort methods.  There's one which ensures you pass in a List of something that implements Comparable, and another which takes a List of anything + a Comparator for that same anything.  Take note that the existing Collections.sort methods do a modified mergesort (google it).

Answer (score 2):

You would have your SomeObj implement the `Comparable` interface and then have your sort interact with it using that interface.

Answer (score 2):

If you can a good way to sort by first "a" then "b" is to implement Comparable in your SomeObj class and make a compareTo method that compares on both a and b. http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10

Answer (score 1):

Decide which has the highest priority. Check the higher priority variable - if they are different, just sort as if you are only sorting on that. If the high priority variable matches, then you have to go back to the lower priority one, and base your whole compare on that.

```
if (obj1.getA() != obj2.getA()) {
    // do compare on As
    // e.g. return onj2.getA() - obj1.getA()
}
else { // A's match, so do compares on B
    // e.g. return obj2.getB() - obj1.getB()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to do that is swap variable values rather than list items. Using this approach you can "sort" the list in different ways simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is a kind of misunderstanding - it's not about sorting by a and then by b, it's a kind of 2 lists in one, and user wants to sort them both independently but without creating the second list, or am I not right?

Answer (score 1):

For sorting List you can use

```
Collections.sort(List list, Comparator c));
```

like in this main method

```
class Pair{
    int a;
    int b;

    public Pair(int a, int b) {
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
    }

    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "["+a+","+b+"]";
    }

    //test
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Comparator<Pair> comparatorA=new Comparator<Pair>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Pair o1, Pair o2) {
                if (o1.a>o2.a) return 1;
                if (o1.a<o2.a) return -1;
                return 0;
            }
        };
        LinkedList<Pair> list=new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(new Pair(1,2));
        list.add(new Pair(2,1));
        list.add(new Pair(3,1));
        list.add(new Pair(1,3));

        Collections.sort(list, comparatorA);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Now you can just make comparator for b value and use Collections.sort with that comparator